# New paperclip fingerprint after modifying style?

Tags: imagemagick, paperclip, rmagick

It looks like Paperclip generates a fingerprint for an attachment only when the original style is changed. I want to keep the original style unchanged but crop one of my other styles (let's call it "listing"). Is there a way to force Paperclip to regenerate a fingerprint if the "listing" style is cropped but the "original" style is not?

Comment: I am looking for the same solution. Why exactly do you want to re-generated the fingerprint ?

Answer (score 0):

I recently added an `image_fingerprint` column to an existing model that has Paperclip images attached.

I forced Paperclip to generate fingerprints for the existing images with the `generate_fingerprint` method on `Paperclip::Attachment`:

```
class Dog
  has_attached_file :image      
  ...
end

Dog.all.each do |dog|
  dog.image_fingerprint = dog.image.generate_fingerprint(dog.image)
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found `generate_fingerprint` no longer works with the latest Paperclip (4.1.1) but the refresh rake task does: e.g. `rake paperclip:refresh CLASS=Dog`.

In my case, I wanted the fingerprint to be created automatically when I ran the the migration that added the fingerprint, so I dug into [the code](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/be04cf02979afe023913d14b802348d96b57420f/lib/tasks/paperclip.rake#L48) and found you can call `reprocess!` on the attachment and that'll also do the trick.